Unix Server - command from one server to another
Inside our PHP code we call the below line to resize images as they are uploaded. Searching our server I found the file at /usr/bin/convert but when I copy this file to a new server the function fails. I am guessing that it is not registered as a function? How would I do that?
 $cmd = "convert -resize \"$newsize\" \"$originalfile\" \"$newfile\"";


Does /usr/bin/convert exist on the new server? If not, you need to install it.

You cannot simply copy/paste an executable program from one server to another and expect it to work. That one file usually references a large number of other files on the file system. convert is part of ImageMagick, you’ll need to install that on your other server using the appropriate installer for it, or via the relevant package manager (apt, yum, etc. depending on the exact flavor of the installed operating system).

convert is usually a tool from ImageMagick. Have you installed ImageMagick?

PHP has an extension to use ImageMagick functionality directly: php8-imagick

Not every server has same tools, binaries, libraries etc. installed on the system. Consider not executing commands on the system using PHP, since that is serious security threat and instead try to use already developed libraries, which allow you to do this easily and safely. Please check this answer on SO, which is dedicated to resizing pictures using PHP.
NOTE: You will have to also have GD installed on your system, but you don't have to worry about sanitizing input file names.
